# subir imagenes multiples con un codigo

Tags: html, imagen, archivo, model

hola comunidad soy nueva en programación utilice este código para subir una imagen  y si me la guarda en mi carpeta y deja el nombre del archivo en la base de datos
como puedo hacerle para poder guardar dos imagenes en la carpeta y estos guardar los datos de ima imagen como si fuera una agregue en mi base de datos otro campo llamado dato1 e imagen 1 pero al parecer solo guarda la primera imagen insertada

[image: base de datos]

en mi **modelo**
[image: modelo]

me deja subir solo una imagen y yo quiero subir mas de una
**controlador**

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Inicio extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('subir_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['titulo'] = 'Subir imagen';
        $this->load->view('headfoot/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('formulario'); //Cargar la vista donde está el formulario
        $this->load->view('headfoot/footer');
    }

    public function subir()
    {
        // Obtenemos el dato input text del formulario
        $dato = $this->input->post("txt_dato"); 
        $dato1 = $this->input->post("txt_dato1"); 
        // Obtenemos el nombre de la imagen elegida
        $nombre_imagen = $_FILES['archivoImagen']['name'];
        $nombre_imagen1 = $_FILES['archivoImagen1']['name1'];

        // Se crea array para pasar al método guardar 
        $data = array("dato" => $dato, "imagen" => $nombre_imagen);
        $data1 = array("dato1" => $dato1, "imagen1" => $nombre_imagen1);

        // Método del modelo que guarda en BD
        $guardar = $this->subir_model->guardar($data);
        $guardar1 = $this->subir_model->guardar1($data1);

        $this->subirImagen(); // Llamamos al método de subir la imagen
    }

    public function subirImagen()
    {
        // Configuracion para la library upload
        $nombreCompleto = $_FILES['archivoImagen']['name'];
        $config['upload_path']          = './assets/images/'; // Carpeta a subr
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'; // Tipos permitidos
        $config['max_size']             = 2000; // Max 2Mb
        $config['max_width']            = 0; // Sin límite de width
        $config['max_height']           = 0; // Sin límite de height
        $config['file_name'] = $nombreCompleto; // Nombre de la imagen

       
        $nombreCompleto1 = $_FILES['archivoImagen1']['name1'];
        $config['upload_path']          = './assets/images/'; // Carpeta a subr
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'; // Tipos permitidos
        $config['max_size']             = 2000; // Max 2Mb
        $config['max_width']            = 0; // Sin límite de width
        $config['max_height']           = 0; // Sin límite de height
        $config['file_name1'] = $nombreCompleto1; // Nombre de la imagen

        // Cargamos la librería. Se recomienda cargar la librería SOLO cuando se usa
        // y no desde el autoload porque así evitas tener cargado siempre un código que 
        // solo se usa cuando se guardar
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        // do_upload es el método que se encarga de subir a la carpeta elegida
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('archivoImagen')) {
            // Si hubo error mandar la vista de error
            $data['titulo'] = 'Subir imagen | Error';
            $data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); //Muestra los errores
            $this->load->view('headfoot/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('formulario_error');
            $this->load->view('headfoot/footer');
        } else {
            // Si hubo exito en la subida, mandar la vista de exito
            $data['titulo'] = 'Subir imagen | Éxito';
            $data['infoImagen'] = $this->upload->data(); // Muestra toda la info de la imagen subida
            $this->load->view('headfoot/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('formulario_exito');
            $this->load->view('headfoot/footer');
        }
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('archivoImagen1')) {
            // Si hubo error mandar la vista de error
            $data['titulo'] = 'Subir imagen | Error';
            $data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); //Muestra los errores
            $this->load->view('headfoot/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('formulario_error');
            $this->load->view('headfoot/footer');
        } else {
            // Si hubo exito en la subida, mandar la vista de exito
            $data['titulo'] = 'Subir imagen | Éxito';
            $data['infoImagen'] = $this->upload->data(); // Muestra toda la info de la imagen subida
            $this->load->view('headfoot/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('formulario_exito');
            $this->load->view('headfoot/footer');
        }
    }
}
```

**vista**

```
     <form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url()?>inicio/subir" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txt_dato" name="txt_dato" value="" placeholder="Pon un dato de texto">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txt_dato1" name="txt_dato1" value="" placeholder="Pon un dato de texto">
             
   <input type="file" name="archivoImagen" /> 
                  <input type="file" name="archivoImagen1" />
```

solo sube el primer archivo el segundo no lo guarda espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Cambia `['name1']` por `['name']` aquí: `$nombre_imagen1 = $_FILES['archivoImagen1']['name1'];` y a ver si con eso ya te vale.  Ah, veo que aquí también lo tienes mal: `$nombreCompleto1 = $_FILES['archivoImagen1']['name1'];`

Comment: no funciono   Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

INSERT INTO `subir` (`dato`, `imagen`) VALUES ('77', 'base.png')

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/subir/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: ¿la clave primaria de esa tabla no es autoincremental?  Fíjate en el error que te da: `Entrada duplicada '0' en la clave "PRIMARIA"`. Eso indica que, cuando haces el INSERT, al no pasarle un valor para la clave primaria que tengas, le asigna un 0, y como previamente ya existe algun registro con ese valor en esa clave dentro de la tabla, no permite su duplicidad.

Comment: Eso se puede arreglar de dos modos: 1) Estructurando ese campo (que imagino que se llama **id**) como AUTOINCREMENTAL dentro de la tabla o bien 2) Pasándole tu un ID específico para ello en la consulta, para que use uno específico que aún no exista.  Lo más habitual es la opción 1.

Comment: me funciono pero ahora como puedo sustituit esa imagen la puedo eliminar asi pero como le hago para subirla ahi mismo public function delete($id){
  $this->subir_model ->delete($id);
  $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'El usuario se eliminó correctamente');
  redirect(base_url()."subir");
 }

Comment: Si lo que necesitas es sustituir la imagen, no hace falta que la borres primero, sino más bien realizar una consulta SQL del tipo UPDATE (previamente has de conocer su id, claro).  La otra opción es borrarla y luego, al realizar el INSERT, usar también el campo **id** para establecerlo durante la inserción (y así el autoincremento no actua).